# Imagemagick no images defined on trim

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to trim the border of an image using `convert -trim image.png`. This gives me `convert-im6.q16: no images defined 'image.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.` Trimming a gif or jpg gives me the same error.

The strange thing is it worked yesterday for a few images*. When I tried to trim a second batch it gave me the error.

```
>>> convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

An I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

*) **Edit 2 July 21:53**

I used `convert -trim *.png` yesterday and that still works. Only trimming a specific file fails.

Comment: Your convert has no output image. The command would be `convert image.png -fuzz XX% -trim result.png`. You could not have used `convert -trim *.png` since you did not specify any output. Convert needs both an input and an output. Wild cards can be used for the input, but not the output. That would more likely have been `mogrify -trim *.png`, which would have overwritten your input images with the trimmed versions.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. `convert -trim *.png` does work somehow. I just tested it in a folder with 3 images: `image1.png`, `image2.png` and `image3.png`. After running the command, two new images are added: `image3-0.png` and `image3-1.png`. These are the trimmed versions of `image1.png` and `image2.png` respectively.

Comment: "Only trimming a specific file fails" As fmw42 said you do not have an output image in this command: convert -trim image.png. Also if something works now in a way that was not intended may not mean it will work in a different release; so it is best to use the recommended commands. Out of interest it should be convert input -trim output

Comment: `Roald` It may work, but notice that it did not process image3.png. You got only image3-0.png image3-1.png, but no image3-2.png. I am surprised that even works that much without issuing an error message. So it does not process the last image. So note that with just one image, you will get an error message `convert: no images defined `x1.png'`. The bottom line is that it is not a proper command. If you want to process all images in a folder, use mogrify, not convert. Then your syntax will work `mogrify -trim *.png`

Comment: Thanks. I was just surprised that the initial *.png command kinda worked. Of course I’ll not use it in the future. @fmw42 you also want to submit an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command may work, but notice that it did not process image3.png. You got only image3-0.png image3-1.png, but no image3-2.png. I am surprised that even works that much without issuing an error message. So it does not process the last image. So note that with just one image, you will get an error message convert: no images defined x1.png'. The bottom line is that it is not a proper ImageMagick convert command. If you want to process all images in a folder, use mogrify, not convert. Then your syntax will work as

```
mogrify -trim *.png
```